# Pandas - adding columns, matching on index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to figure out if Panda's, when adding two series together, automatically matches on index or if it simply adds by element position.  If its just by position, is there a way to get it to add on index?  I've looked at merging, but I'm not very clear if the key in this case can be the index of both...

For example, if I have do DFs:

```
df1 = index  value
        0      10
        1      12
        2      15
        4      20


df2 = index  value
        0      10
        1      10
        3      10
        4      10
```

and I want to add `df1[total] = df1[value] + df2[value] =`

```
df1 = index  value
        0      20
        1      22
        2      15
        3      10
        4      30
```

Thanks for your help in advance!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because of the [intrinsic data alignment](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/dsintro.html?highlight=alignment#intro-to-data-structures) in pandas, you can use `add` with `fill_value=0` and it will sum these two series based on index alignment.

```
df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
```

Input:

```
df1 = pd.Series([10]*4,index=[0,1,3,4])

df2 = pd.Series([10,12,15,20], index=[0,1,2,4])

df1.add(df2,fill_value=0)
```

Output:

```
0    20.0
1    22.0
2    15.0
3    10.0
4    30.0
dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 4):

#### Just do this:

```
pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=1).sum(axis=1)
```

`pd.concat` will merge the 2(or more) frames and match based on index. `sum(axis=1)` just sums across the rows.

#### Here's the working example:

```
#create the example data
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,2,4],'value':[10,12,15,20]}).set_index('index')
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'index':[0,1,3,4],'value':[10,10,10,10]}).set_index('index')
```

The above will give you:

```
In [7]: pd.concat([df1,df2],axis=1).sum(axis=1)
Out[7]:
index
0    20.0
1    22.0
2    15.0
3    10.0
4    30.0
dtype: float64
```

### Timing Update

A comment wanted to see which solution is faster. tldr, using `.add()` is about 2x faster than `pd.concat`, but if you use `.align` explicitly, it'll be even faster, albeit marginally

```
# create example dataframe
N=1000000
np.random.seed(666)
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0,1000, size=N),"B":np.random.randint(0,1000, size=N)}, index=np.arange(0,N,1))
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(0,1000, size=N),"B":np.random.randint(0,1000, size=N)}, index=np.arange(0,N,1))

# punch a few holes to mismatch integers
df1 = df1.loc[np.random.choice(df1.index,int(.8*N), replace=False),:].sort_index()
df2 = df2.loc[np.random.choice(df1.index,int(.8*N), replace=False),:].sort_index()

# define functions
def summatch1(x,y):
    return pd.concat([x,y],axis=1).sum(axis=1)

def summatch2(x,y):
    return x.add(y,fill_value=0)

def summatch3(x,y):
    z = x.merge(y,how='outer',suffixes=['1','2'],left_index=True, right_index=True).fillna(0)
    return z.A1+z.A2

def summatch4(x,y):
    p1,p2 = x.align(y,join='outer', fill_value=0)
    return p1+p2

# time them
%timeit summatch1(df1.A, df2.A)
%timeit summatch2(df1.A, df2.A)
%timeit summatch3(df1.loc[:,['A']], df2.loc[:,['A']])
%timeit summatch4(df1.A, df2.A)
```

#### Results

Times are reported in the following order:

1. `pd.concat`
2. `df1.add`
3. `pd.merge`
4. `df1.align`

**800k rows in `df1` and `df2`**

```
79.7 ms ± 1.52 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
36.6 ms ± 1.41 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
40.2 ms ± 1.99 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
31.3 ms ± 1.34 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

**80k rows in `df1` and `df2`**

```
7.2 ms ± 221 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
4.08 ms ± 90.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
5.14 ms ± 43.7 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
3.76 ms ± 30.6 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: Will this be faster or slow than @scott Boston answer of adding two series with pad value=0?

Comment: @limKaizhuo not exactly timely (pun not intended) but I timed the various options. `.add` is faster but using `.align` is even faster, albeit marginally.